# R- Shiny - how to change color of legends in pie chart?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the color of legends in piechart.
Here is the code:

```
library(ECharts2shiny)
library(shiny)

dat5 <- c(rep("Female", 3376), rep("Male", 2180))

ui <- shinyUI(
dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "PSM"),
dashboardBody(
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel(
loadEChartsLibrary(),  tags$div(id="test5", 
style="width:60%;height:300px;"),                                                                           
deliverChart(div_id = "test5"))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){  
renderPieChart(div_id = "test5", data = dat5 )    })
```

Can anybody help me how to change the legends color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it helps:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dat5 <- c(rep("Female", 3376), rep("Male", 2180))
app <- shinyApp(
ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "PSM"),
                dashboardSidebar(),
                dashboardBody(
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel(tags$div(id="test5", 
                                        style="width:60%;height:300px;"),                                                                           
                        plotOutput("pie_chart"))
                    ))))
                    ),

                      server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){  
                        output$pie_chart <- renderPlot({
                          df <- table(dat5)
                          cols <- rainbow(length(df))
                          pie(df, col = cols)

                        })
                          })
)

runApp(app)
```

Comment: It would be better if we can assign pie wise color.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to vote positive for the answer, so others can find it easier